# Struggling with recurring login screen on rpi

Tags: login

Read this a couple times googling it but i cannot resolve it with the given solutions.

When i connect to rpi with vncviewer i enter the "pi"-account password in vncviewer and indeed get a graphical desktop on my display, demanding user and password again. When i enter that the screen goes black for a couple seconds and then the login window comes up again.

I also tried creating a new user and logging in via that account, here i just get "access is denied" by vnc viewer.

Thanks for any input,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

The vnc password is NOT generally the login password, and would vary by user.

Run the `vncpasswd` utilty to set.

Normally you should be prompted to enter the password the first time you run vncserver.

Try `man vncpasswd` for more detail.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Although an incorrect password does not seem to be the issue here. When i deliberately enter a wrong password in the login screen i get a message telling me about it, not the "usual" black screen. 
Further, i set a new password on vncpasswd anyway but without success.